# Stopping sprites from toppling off platform

Tags: 2d, unity, sprites, platformer

I am new to Unity and am trying to create a simple 2d platformer. I have applied a box collider to my player sprite and the floor/platform its standing on. Now when I go over the platform, it toppes off of it as expected, but I want it to simple fall off it instead of toppling. How can I do this?

Also I saw a video of Unity Live Training in which he was using a separate circular collider for the player's feet. When I did this, the sprite started rolling.

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an "fixed angle" option on Rigidbody2D component,enabling that works

Comment: If you're answering your own question, you should give a definitive answer. Not a suggestion that *might* work. You should know if it works or not, since you're the one asking the question. Please flesh this answer out to include more information about how to enable restraints, and why this will solve the problem.

Comment: For me it did work. As for why this will solve the problem- the name of the option, "fixed angle" is pretty self explanatory,it does not allow angle to change(fixes it) and thus will stop rotation.